# How to access RHEL non-UBI content when the host is an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, redhat, redhat-ubi

The Red Hat Universal Base Image (UBI) [FAQ](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/ubi-faq) claims that

> ### 8. Will applications built on UBI have access to the same content as images built on a non-UBI base image?
>
> Yes, but accessing non-UBI content requires a Red Hat subscription and renders containers built with non-UBI content non-redistributable.

When I launch a UBI container on a registered, subscribed host, the list of available RPM repositories is different depending on whether I created the host from a RHEL ISO (VirtualBox VM, in this case) or launched an EC2 instance from a RHEL AMI. The UBI container on the EC2 instance does not have access to the full set of RPM package repositories.

For example:

### UBI8 container on an RHEL8 EC2 instance

```
[ec2-user@ip-WWW-XXX-YYY-ZZZ ~]$ podman run --rm -it ubi7 yum repolist all | wc -l
41
```

### UBI8 container on an RHEL8 VirtualBox VM

```
[neirbowj@rhel8 ~]$ podman run --rm -it ubi8 yum repolist all | wc -l
427
```

Why is this and how can I modify the EC2 environment so that I can access the full set of RPM package repositories from within a UBI container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this difference is that the RHEL AMIs ship with a non-default value of `/etc/rhsm/rhsm.conf:manage_repos = 0`. Setting `manage_repos = 1` will make a RHEL EC2 instance behave like a RHEL VM with respect to RPM package repository access.

See the current RHSM configuration with:

```
sudo subscription-manager config --list
```

Note that square brackets indicate which values are defaults.

Enable RHSM to manage repos with:

```
sudo subscription-manager config --rhsm.manage_repos=1
```